# Write a lambda function to retrieve the CSV file stored in AWS S3

Tags: csv, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have seen many Lambda functions to get the CSV file data from S3 in python, Node.js but I have been trying to write the function using Go.

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func main() {
 
    file, err := os.Open("testcsv.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, _ := reader.ReadAll()
 
    fmt.Println(records)
}
```

This is the way to read the CSV file but how to write this for AWS Lambda Function?

Answer (score 1):

you need have the sdk set up and [amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html) will be a good start

once you have the code compile with os as `linux` then deploy in aws as zip file . Please note that handler name should same as binary

more details on deployment  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-package.html)